# php class - Make a tiny wrapper

Tags: php, class, instance, wrapper

I'm currently making a class plugin for a post like system.

However, I would like to make a kind of class wrapper to use it as a simple function. But I need to register in my class some scripts and constant then run the class.

With the current wrapper I made it re-execute the _contruct function of the class. I want to initialize the class then when I call the tiny wrapper it will not execute the contrucct instance and only get the right class function.

How can I make this? Do it make sense?

Here my example code:

```
if(!class_exists('Post_Like')) {

    class Post_Like {

        static private $instance = null;

        static public function getInstance() {
            if(self::$instance == null) {
                self::$instance = new self;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function __construct() {
            $this->define_constants();
            // Load public/admin CSS and JS.
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
            // register actions for ajax
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_like', array($this, 'post_like') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_like', array($this, 'post_like') );
        }

        public function define_constants() {
            define('POST_LIKE_PATH', trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__))));
            define('POST_LIKE_URL', site_url(str_replace(trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/',ABSPATH)), '', POST_LIKE_PATH)));
        }


        public function enqueue_scripts() { 
            // enqueue js scripts
        }

        public function post_like() {
           // do some stuff 
        }


        public function post_already_like() {
           // do some stuff         
        }

        // I want to wrap this function to use it anywhere easily
        public function get_post_like() {
           // do some stuff
        }

    }

}

new Post_Like();

if(!function_exists('Post_Like')) {
    /**
    * Tiny wrapper function
    */
    function get_post_like() {
        $Post_Like = Post_Like::getInstance();
        return $Post_Like->get_post_like(); // it execute _contruct, I want to avoid that
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `new Post_Like();` you are creating an instance of the class, executing the constructor.

If you want to avoid that, and as you have defined this as a singleton, you can make the contructor private.

Try the following:

```
if(!class_exists('Post_Like')) {

    class Post_Like {

        static private $instance = null;

        static public function getInstance() {
            if(self::$instance == null) {
                self::$instance = new self;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        private function __construct() {
            $this->define_constants();
            // Load public/admin CSS and JS.
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
            // register actions for ajax
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_like', array($this, 'post_like') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_like', array($this, 'post_like') );
        }

        public function define_constants() {
            define('POST_LIKE_PATH', trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__))));
            define('POST_LIKE_URL', site_url(str_replace(trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/',ABSPATH)), '', POST_LIKE_PATH)));
        }


        public function enqueue_scripts() {
            // enqueue js scripts
        }

        public function post_like() {
            // do some stuff
        }


        public function post_already_like() {
            // do some stuff
        }

        // I want to wrap this function to use it anywhere easily
        public function get_post_like() {
            // do some stuff
        }

    }

}

// new Post_Like(); <-- unnecessary

// you need to check for a function called 'get_post_like' rather than the class name
if(!function_exists('get_post_like')) {
    function get_post_like() { 
        return Post_Like::getInstance()->get_post_like();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However without running the class new Post_Like(); it can't work. Scripts are not register because the filter was called before the get post like is ran. But if I keep the line it works but I still have double or several declarations of the constructor. So it doesn't solved my issue. I made an extends class to make it work finally.